# Hibernate Unknown entity:

Tags: java, hibernate

I devised a sample crud operation but I came across an issue related with persisting object to the database , which means C(create). I could'nt solve it although I defined annotations in the entity. How can I troubleshoot it? Thank you.

Here are the codes below.

Customer.java

```
package entities;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="CUSTOMER",schema="CRUD")
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="musseq",sequenceName="musSEQ",allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="musseq",strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="SURNAME")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name="DEPARTMENT")
    private String department;

    public Customer() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Customer(String name, String surname, String department) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.department = department;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }


}
```

CustomerDAO.java

```
package daos;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import entities.Customer;
import util.HibernateUtil;

public class CustomerDAO implements ICustomerDAO {

    @Override
    public void addCustomer(Customer customer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction trx = session.getTransaction();

        try {

            trx.begin();

            session.persist(customer);

            trx.commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (trx != null)
                trx.rollback();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public List<Customer> getAllCustomer() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction trx = session.getTransaction();
        try {

            trx.begin();

            List<Customer> liste = session.createQuery("from Customer").list();

            trx.commit();

            return liste;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (trx != null)
                trx.rollback();
        } finally {

            session.close();

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteCustomer(int customerId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction trx = session.getTransaction();

        Customer customerObj= null;

        try {

            trx.begin();

            customerObj = session.load(Customer.class, customerId);
            session.delete(customerObj);

            trx.commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (trx != null)
                trx.rollback();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

    }

}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="CRUD">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">123</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">CRUD</property>
  <property name="hibernate.default_schema">CRUD</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">2</property>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
  <mapping class="entities.Customer"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

HibernateUtil.java

```
package util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            return configuration.buildSessionFactory(
                    new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build());
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: entities.Customer
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:766)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:742)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:747)
at daos.CustomerDAO.addCustomer(CustomerDAO.java:24)
at servlets.CustomerServlet.doGet(CustomerServlet.java:38)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Show us the HibernateUtil. Also, why a name on sessionFactory in xml?

Comment: where does entities.Student come from?

Comment: Are specifying the `<context:component-scan base-package="somePackage" />` somewhere in your application?

Comment: No. the problem causes in session.persiste(customer) n CustomerDAO

Comment: How can I solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the table name to **customer** . i think it will solve the issue.
On Unix, table names are case sensitive. On Windows, they are not.

Comment: I changed the table name (Customers ,CUSTOMERS,customer) but the issue cannot be solved. It still appears unknown entity .  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: entities.Customer

Answer (score 0):

The unknown entity's name is Student. Do you have the wrong exception copied here or just the name is wrong?

Comment: The problem comes from session.persist(customer) in CustomerDAO. How can I solve it out?

Comment: I have checked you code again. There doesn't seem to be an issue to me. Usually this is a problem caused by the missing mapping of the entity, but I can see it is in your hibernate setting file. Since you have set the hbm2ddl.auto to update, even the table is missing, it still wouldn't cause any problem. I would only suggest you check if the configuration is correctly loaded or the package name of the entity is correct.